# All natural numbers which sum up to N and where the inverses sum up to one

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, recursion, numbers

I have a problem to solve. `N` natural number is given. I need to find a list of natural numbers which sum up to that given number and at the same time the inverses up to 1.

```
a + b + c + ... = N
1/a + 1/b + 1/c + ... = 1
```

`a`, `b`, `c` don't have to be unique.

I have come up with following code in Java. It works for simple cases, but incredibly slow for already for `N > 1000`.

**How can I rewrite the method so it works fast even for millions?** Maybe, I should drop off recursion or cut off some of branches with mathematical trick which I miss?

SSCEE:

```
private final static double ONE = 1.00000001;

public List<Integer> search (int number) {
    int bound = (int)Math.sqrt(number) + 1;
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(bound);

    if (number == 1) {
        list.add(1);
        return list;
    }

    for (int i = 2; i <= bound; i++) {
        list.clear();
        if (simulate(number, i, list, 0.0)) break;
    }

    return list;
}


//TODO: how to reuse already calculated results?
private boolean search (int number, int n, List<Integer> list, double sum) {
    if (sum > ONE) {
        return false;
    }

    //would be larger anyway
    double minSum = sum + 1.0 / number;
    if (minSum > ONE) {
        return false;
    }

    if (n == 1) {
        if (minSum < 0.99999999) {
            return false;
        }

        list.add(number);
        return true;
    }

    boolean success = false;
    for (int i = 2; i < number; i++) {
        if (number - i > 0) {
            double tmpSum = sum + 1.0 / i;
            if (tmpSum > ONE) continue;

            list.add(i);
            success = search(number - i, n - 1, list, tmpSum);
            if (!success) {
                list.remove(list.size() - 1);
            }

            if (success) break;
        }
    }

    return success;
}
```

Comment: I think `1/a + 1/b + 1/c + ... = N` is a typo, that should be `= 1`, shouldn't it?

Comment: you said inverse list should sum up to *1* (your formula says *N*): a + b + c + ... = N 1/a + 1/b + 1/c + ... = **1**

Comment: I think you should expect a magnitude of O(n^2) for runtime. If you implement a smart pruning, you may save a constant factory, which does IMHO not pay off. I think you cannot solve this with floating point arithmetics. Optimizations should probably go to java coding.

Comment: Just to make it clear, {a, b, ...} should be integers, right? Also, do you allow  both positive and negative numbers?

Comment: Should a, b, c, ... de dinstinct?

Comment: @Thomash probably not, as OP mentioned that: *a, b, c don't have to be unique* (quite unclear, indeed)

Comment: @adrianp, integers, don't have to be distinct. For N=4, solution would be {2,2} for N=16 solution is {4,4,4,4} for N=11 solution is {2,3,6}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The paper ["A Theorem on Partitions", 1963 by Graham, R. L.](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ronspubs/63_02_partitions.pdf) shows that for N > 77 there is a solution where the numbers used are dinstinct and propose an algorithm to find such a decomposition.

The algorithm is the following:

- If N is less than 333 , use a precomputed table to fetch the result.
- If N is odd, find a decomposition `d1, d2, d3, d4, ..., dk` for `(N-179)/2`, then `3, 7, 78, 91, 2*d1, 2*d2, 2*d3, ..., 2*dk` is a decomposition for N
- If N is even, find a decomposition `d1, d2, d3, d4, ..., dk` for `(N-2)/2`, then `2, 2*d1, 2*d2, 2*d3, ..., 2*dk` is a decomposition for N

But since you don't care about having distinct numbers in the decomposition, you can reduce the size of the table for precomputed results to 60 and in case N is odd, find a decomposition `d1, d2, d3, d4, ..., dk` for `(N-9)/2`, then `3, 6, 2*d1, 2*d2, 2*d3, ..., 2*dk` is a decomposition for N.

Comment: `(N-179)/2` that's insane!

Comment: Since you don't care about dincstinct numbers, you don't need this 179, I have updated the answer.

Comment: where `60` and `(N-9)/2` comes from?

Comment: You should read the paper. `(N-9)/2` comes from the fact that if `d1, ..., dk` is a decomposition for `(N-9)/2`, then `3, 6, 2*d1, ..., 2*dk` is a decomposition for `N`.

Comment: 60 is not actually the minimal number. The minimal number is 55. There is no valid decomposition for 23 so for the number 55 you can not use this algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

First, change the second condition so that you don't have to perform any floating point arithmatic. Change (1/a+1/b+1/c)=1  to bc+ac+ab = abc. You can calculate this with O(k) divisions (Hint: Calculate the right side first).

Second, consolidate your numbers. Example: if you have a,b,c,a,b as input, consolidate the dupes and store it as two a, two b and one c.

Third, there is a DP based solution to solve the first problem efficiently. You would have to store all the partial answers as well. However you can store the partial answers quite efficiently. Eg. Store "x=bc+ac+ab" and "y=abc" as the partial solution. When you add d to the mix, you have xnew = x*d+y, and ynew=y*d .

If you use these three pointers, your solution could be more efficient.

Answer (score -2):

If the numbers don't have to be integers `a = b = c = ... = sqrt(N)` is a solution.

If negative numbers are allowed, then find `a` and `b` such that `8a+3b+1=N` (you can compute them with [Euclide's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)) and then the list you want is:
the number 3 (3a times), the number 2 (2b times) and the number 1 (1-a-b times)

Comment: they have to be integers. negative are not allowed.